# How to get safe area frame of programmatically created ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

> Note : Not created ViewController in storyboard

I created ViewController programmatically after giving support for safe guard now my problem is that how i can got his height?

I try following thing but no luck

```
let guide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
let height = guide.layoutFrame.size.height
print("\(height)")
print("\(self.view.frame.height)")
height = 812.0, self.view height = 812.0
```

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

A `safeAreaLayoutGuide`, which is iOS 11+, is meant for auto layout and to try to get a *frame* is close to trying to make orange juice from a lemon.

If what you want is to find out is what you can *safely* use for a frame, maybe try something like this:

**Create a transparent view:**

```
let mySafeView = UIView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mySafeView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    mySafeView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(mySafeView)

    // if needed, send this view to the back of the hierarchy

    view.sendSubview(toBack: mySafeView)
}
```

**Next, in your constraint-building code attach it to the *true* anchors:**

```
// create generic layout guides

let layoutGuideTop = UILayoutGuide()
view.addLayoutGuide(layoutGuideTop)

let layoutGuideBottom = UILayoutGuide()
view.addLayoutGuide(layoutGuideBottom)

let margins = view.layoutMarginsGuide
view.addLayoutGuide(margins)

// get correct top/bottom margins based on iOS version

if #available(iOS 11, *) {
    let guide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    layoutGuideTop.topAnchor.constraintEqualToSystemSpacingBelow(guide.topAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
    layoutGuideBottom.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToSystemSpacingBelow(guide.bottomAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
} else {
    layoutGuideTop.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    layoutGuideBottom.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
}
    mySafeView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuideTop.topAnchor).isActive = true
    mySafeView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    mySafeView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuideBottom.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    mySafeView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
```

**Finally, get the frame size:**

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    print(mySafeView.frame)
}
```

On an iPhone 6 plus running iOS 11.1 you get:

**(0.0, 28.0, 414.0, 716.0)**

On an iPhone 6 plus running iOS 9.0 you get:

**(0.0, 20.0, 414.0, 716.0)**

Comment: i have requirement that scrollview should be scroll to top view. that's why i need safeAreaLayoutGuide height

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question. Using auto layout anchors, just set the scrollview's top anchor like my code does for the transparent view. If you're talking the content window, doesn't my code give you the values you need?

Comment: i need to calculate the height for scrolling the drawer top to bottom and bottom to top that's why i need the value of the safe area

Answer (score 0):

First off you can't do it in the **viewDidLoad**. You have to wait till **viewDidLayoutSubviews**

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    myGlobalVars.sceneRect = view.frame
    
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        myGlobalVars.topSafeArea    = view.safeAreaInsets.top
        myGlobalVars.bottomSafeArea = view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
    } else {
        myGlobalVars.topSafeArea    = topLayoutGuide.length
        myGlobalVars.bottomSafeArea = bottomLayoutGuide.length
    }
}
```